# Why str.length() is output as a char?

Tags: c++, string, char, string-length

Here is my c++ code:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str1;
    cin>>str1;
    int j=-1;
    cout<<typeid(str1.length()).name()<<endl;
    cout<<(j>str1.length())<<endl;
    int len=str1.length();
    cout<<len<<' '<<(j>=len);
}
```

I input:

```
abc
```

And the outcome is:

```
j
1
3 0
```

**As can be seen, `typeid(str1.length()).name()` is `j`, and `-1>str1.length()`**

I wonder why this is the case

Comment: That's not what it says.

Comment: Note: Using `bits/stdc++.h` is usually unnecessary and makes your code non-portable. Likewise `using namepsace std` to avoid typing `std::` misses the point of the prefix: To separate Standard Library code from your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wonder why this is the case
>
> `typeid(str1.length()).name()` is j

Because that is how your language implementation happens to mangle the type name. On my system it is m.

To be clear, the type is same as `std::size_t` which is alias of an unsigned integer type.

> and -1>str1.length()

This is because, being a negative number, -1 is outside the representable values of an unsigned type and when converted to the representable range, it becomes larger than 3. In fact, the -1 converted to unsigned will be the maximum representable value of that type.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `str1.length()` is `std::string::size_type`, which is some unsigned integral type (usually `size_t`). In the comparison `j>str1.length()`, the signed integer `j` is converted to that unsigned type modulo `2^n` for some `n`, whereby `-1` becomes `2^n-1` - a large positive value.

Comment: `std::string::size_type` is always `std::size_t`.